# How to check radio buttons values and if else..?

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

I need to check the values for a list of radio buttons and a select.
Both a radio button and a select value can NOT be selected at the same time.

I have this now but it only works if I select the 1 radio button in the list of radio buttons.
userdevice is a radio button list. And tags is the select.

```
var isChecked = $('input[name=userdevice]').prop('checked');
    if (isChecked) {
    var userdevice=$('input[name="userdevice"]:checked').val();
    }else{
    var userdevice="";
    }

    var tags=$('select[id=tags]').val()

     if ((userdevice.length > 0) && (tags.length < 1)){
    //if userdevice - a radio button is selected - run this...and this only works if the first radio button is selected...

     }else if((userdevice.length < 1 ) && (tags.length > 0)){
    //if a tag in the select is selected - run this... 

     }else {
    //if both user device and tags are not selected, then run this....
    }
```

Any input really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you please add this to a `jsfiddle` with your HTML content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `prop('checked');` into:

`var isChecked = $('input[name=userdevice]').is(':checked');`

I tested. Result of `isChecked` was always false.

Full code:

```js
var isChecked = $('input[name=userdevice]').is(':checked');
if (isChecked) {
  var userdevice = $('input[name="userdevice"]:checked').val();
} else {
  var userdevice = "";
}
var tags = $('select[id=tags]').val()
if ((userdevice.length > 0) && (tags.length < 1)) {
  //if userdevice - a radio button is selected - run this...and this only works if the first radio button is selected...
} else if ((userdevice.length < 1) && (tags.length > 0)) {
  //if a tag in the select is selected - run this... 
} else {
  //if both user device and tags are not selected, then run this....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code sample, it seems that you are using `val().length` to check for whether particular item is selected or not ? In my opinion (and if that is what you are going for,) using `selected` and `checked` properties directly would be better.

Just an idea

```
  var hasSelected = 
  $('input[name=userdevice]:checked, #tags option:selected')  // if has any selection
  .map(function(index,elm){
     $(elm).is('input') ? /* if only radio button selected */  : null ; 
     $(elm).is('option')? /* if only select option selected */ : null ; 
     return $(this);                                                   
  }).get().length;

  (hasSelected < 1) ? /* if NO selection */ : null ;
```